# 2 iterations for one route layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, iterator

I have a polyline shp file, which has 3 routes. I need to find the overlap segments of any two routes, and then merge all the overlap segments with the original 3 routes to get a new polyline shp file for the further analysis. Now my method is to use two iterations to obtain the results. The following picture shows the method I used for now. In the model, AllRoute.shp includes route0, route1 and route2.

[image]

However, I have to use the same method for 500 routes. Can anyone help me with adding another iteration to the existing model?

Comment: There can be only one iterator per model so you need to use a submodel. However, I suspect this would be a lot easier to do using ArcPy.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, I made it by using Python script. Thanks.

Comment: Excellent - it would be great if you could post your script as an answer to benefit the next people facing the same scenario.  It is perfectly OK and encouraged to answer your own question and even to accept it.

Comment: Hi PolyGeo, I am sorry that I don't know how to format the code. Your edits would be appreciated.

Comment: I've formatted it (highlighted text then clicked the **`{}`** button) but please now cut/paste it into an answer.  At the moment you have an "answer" in your question which does not follow our protocols for focussed Q&A.  Be sure to take the 2-minute [Tour] to learn more about how the site works.

Comment: Thanks for your information. By the way, within the code, there are a lot of intersection are empty, which means those two routes don't have overlap segments. I want to use a IF...ELSE...  to only keep the non-empty records, but I don't know how to write the code for the empty overlap part. Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:/Users/TL/Desktop/ModelTest/SeperateRoutes"

featureClasses = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

i = 1

for fc1 in featureClasses:
    j = 1
    for fc2 in featureClasses:
        inputFC = [fc1, fc2]
        outputFC = "C:/Users/TL/Desktop/ModelTest/Intersect/Intersect%sto%s.shp" % (i, j)
        arcpy.Intersect_analysis(inputFC, outputFC, "ALL", "", "LINE")
        j += 1
    i += 1


print "Done!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain about what you are trying to accomplish (a picture might help) but I have a suspicion that it may be easier to accomplish by converting your polyline features into linear route events so that you can overlay them within a single process using [Overlay Route Events](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/roads-and-highways-toolbox/overlay-route-events.htm):

> Overlays two or more event feature layers against a target network and
>   outputs a feature class or event table that represents the union of
>   the input.

Comment: I have some background for the Python, but never used Arcpy before. As I go over the tutorial, I noticed that the Arcpy would give me more freedom to realize the things I want. Anyway, thanks to your comments for the question I posted here.